# Apache Velocity foreach loop #continue

Tags: apache, foreach, velocity

Is there a `#continue` command for jump to next iteration in `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 17):

I have a bunch of velocity code but I don't think I've ever seen this.  I believe you have to use a `#foreach` and then use and `#if` to check your skip condition within the loop. [The VTL guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html) doesn't seem have a better approach.

Comment: Correct.  Velocity is a simple template engine, not a full scripting language.

Comment: Problem was i've a lot of #if, so like in switch-case construct, i wanto to skip to end after the first match.

Comment: @NathanBubna Ok, but it has break for example.

Comment: Having #break doesn't make it a full scripting language where you can expect all the standard features. Velocity is extensible, though, so you can make your own #continue directive. It's also open source, so you can lobby to have your #continue added by default.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html), Apache Velocity does not appear to have a #continue function for its [foreach](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#loops) loop.

In case it might help, it does have a foreach [break](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.6.2/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/directive/Break.html) directive, [added](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.1/changes.html) [in](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-612) 2008.